# find a vector perpendicular to two 3d vectors

Tags: vectors

The question in my textbook says "Find a vector perpendicular to both (-1, 1, -3) and (-2, 3, -3)"

The solutions says [image]

What I do not understand is why they say "let z be a constant." I can only guess that it has something do with the fact the the two given vectors have the same z coordinate.

Comment: both answers are helpful.

Comment: Glad to be of help. See the image I sent. I believe it will nail the point home.

Comment: @Vector does it matter if I set x or y as the known constant? I am sure it would work out just as fine as if we set z as the constant.

Comment: Indeed you can set any of the three coordinates, and then calculate the other two. The point is that you have a system of two linear equations with three unknowns, so it has an infinity of solution; if you set the value of one unknown arbitrarily, then you have a system of two linear equations with two unknowns, and that has exactly one solution (assuming the two equations are independent, which in your case they are).

Comment: @moonriver, as someone else as said, yes you can. In fact, I will show you the solution if you fixed x or y as the constant. You can check my answer again.

Comment: Take the cross product of the two vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think about the geometry of the problem you will see that there are infinitely many vectors perpendicular to those two, but they are all scalar multiples of one another. So to make your algebra easier, you can assume that you are looking for the one whose $z$ coordinate is the particular number
$\lambda$. Then you need to solve just two equations in the two unknowns $x$ and $y$ to find out what they are (as expressions involving $\lambda$).

Answer (score 2):

There are an infinite number of vectors that are orthogonal to both vectors.

However, if the z coordinate of the orthogonal vector is known, then the vector can be narrowed down to just one. Thus, it is helpful to assume the z coordinate is already known and work from there. See the graph
[1]: https://www.desmos.com/3d/e09dd24277

Notice that a specific t value will correspond with a specific z coordinate by our construction.

Edit: I edited the graph to show what would happen if y was our constant instead.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that vector that you are looking for is $(x,y,z)$. Then $<(x,y,z),(-1,1,3)>=0$ and $<(x,y,z),(-2,3,-3)>=0$ since it is perpendicular to both of these vectors. You get linear equations:
\begin{equation}
-x+y+3z=0\\
-2x+3y-3z=0
\end{equation}
By solving this system, you will get infinitely many solutions, depending on one variable (in the solution it is variable $z$). For every value $z$ your vector will be perpendicular to the two given vectors. You do not need infinitely many, you need JUST ONE, so you pick a value for $z$. All other vectors that are perpendicular to the two given vectors will be colinear to your vector, so you have determined it precisely. Note that this is not true in higher dimensions (In $\mathbb{R}^4$ you would get a perpendicular plane for two given vectors).